# How do I amend a hover script to work with click functions too?

Tags: jquery, function, click, hover

I have the following script on [this page](http://nickputman.com/test/) which handles the fading in and out of a div to change the colour of leaves in the nav bar when hovering over them, the sliding of a contact form, and the fading of the content of one page into another:

```
$(function ()
{

    var newHash = "",
        $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
        $pageWrap = $("#page-wrap"),
        baseHeight = 0,
        $el,
    curTab = "#index";

    $("nav").delegate("a.fade", "click", function ()
    {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");


//        $(this).addClass("current", 3000);
//        $("#contact").removeClass("current", 3000);
        return false;
    });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function ()
    {

        newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

        if (newHash)
        {
            $pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
            baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

            $mainContent
                .find("#guts")
                .fadeOut(500, function ()
                {
                    $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function ()
                    {
                        $pageWrap.animate({ height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px" }, function ()
                        {
                            $mainContent.fadeIn(500);
                            $pageWrap.css("height", "auto"); 
                        });

//                        $("nav a").removeClass("current");
//                    curTab = "#" + /^(.+)\..+$/.exec(newHash)[1];
//                    $(curTab).addClass("current");
                    });
                });
        };
    });

$("#contact").click(function ()
{
    $("#panel").slideDown("slow");  

    return false;
});

$(".close").click(function ()
{
    $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
    return false;
});

$("nav a").hover(
    function() {
        $(".current", this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, {
            duration: 300,
            specialEasing: {
                opacity: 'linear',
            },

        });
    }, function() {
        $(".current", this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, {
            duration: 2000,
            specialEasing: {
                opacity: 'linear',
            },

    });
});


    $(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

I am now wanting to get this working with some click functions, i.e. so that the leaf of the current page remains green rather than brown, and the contact leaf is green when the contact form is open, but I am not sure how to do this.  For instance, I have tried changing the delegate to this:

```
$("nav").delegate("a.fade", "click", function ()
    {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#panel").slideUp("slow");

        $(".current", this).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, {
            duration: 300,
            specialEasing: {
                opacity: 'linear',
            },

        });
```

But the page being clicked on does not stay green.  As soon as the mouse is moved out of the div it returns to brown.

I would be grateful if someone could help me get this working.

Thanks,

Nick

**HTML ADDED:**

```
<div id="nav1">
     <a href="index.html" class="fade" id="index">

     <div class="nav-image"><img src="images/bodhi-leaf-brown.png"></div>

     <div class="current"><img src="images/bodhi-leaf-green.png"></div>
     <div class="text"><img src="images/home.png"></div>

     </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a class to the element when it's clicked. Then, inside your hover functions, first check if the element has that class and only proceed with the hover effect if it does not have this class.

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2J8Cc/

```
$('div').hover(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked')){
        $(this).fadeTo(250,1);
    }
},function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked')){
        $(this).fadeTo(250,0.5);
    }
})
.click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('clicked');     
});
```

**EDIT**
In response to the OP's comment on this answer, here's how I'd do it given the HTML he's provided:

```
$("nav a").hover(
    function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked')){
            $(".current", this).stop().animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, {
                duration: 300,
                specialEasing: {
                    opacity: 'linear',
                },

            });
        }
    }, function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked')){
            $(".current", this).stop().animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, {
                duration: 2000,
                specialEasing: {
                    opacity: 'linear',
                },
            });
        }
})
.click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure how adding a class is going to work, as the fade on hover (fading in green leaf) is controlled by fading in a DIV with absolute positioning over the top of another image.  I have added the HTML for one of the nav links to the end of my original question to make this clearer.

Comment: I don't see how it would be any different from the example I posted. But I've updated my answer to show how's I'd modify your specific code. Let me know if that helps, or if I'm missing something.

Comment: Thanks Max. I have marked your answer as the correct answer. It solves part of the hover/click function issue I have.  The other problem is how to handle the transitions between page changes (i.e. the colour of the leaves when the user changes page). I have asked a more specific question about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878199/script-not-fading-out-non-active-navigation-links)

Answer (score -1):

I think it should work like this:

1. when leaf is clicked just fade and on complete attach some css class which will keep the leaf green.
2. when another leaf is clicked just reset all leafs to brown(if one has let's say green class, you can fade out) and do rest like in point 1

So it really should work like reset leafs to brown and leave one clicked green.

If you need code, just ask:D

Comment: Thanks. As with my above comment, I am not sure how adding a class is going to work, as the fade on hover (fading in green leaf) is controlled by fading in a DIV with absolute positioning over the top of another image. I have added the HTML for one of the nav links to the end of my original question to make this clearer.

Comment: @f1ames: Yours is not really an answer to the question, and the OP _"needs"_ code and already _"asked"_... that's the whole point of this place.

Comment: @f1ames yes, code would be good, bearing in mind my previous comment above. Thanks.