# Script not fading out non-active navigation links

Tags: jquery, if-statement, jquery-animate, this

I am using a script on [this page](http://nickputman.com/test/) which does everything I want it to, i.e. changing the colour of the leaves in the nav bar on hover, fading between pages using a hash method, and the sliding of a contact form.  The only thing that isn't working is the fading out of the .current div in the non-active nav links (i.e. when the user clicks on a leaf to change the page, I would like the green leaf on the page that has been left to fade out).

I was hoping that adding this code would handle the fading out of the links other than the active one, but when I add it to the delegate click function all leaves stay brown, i.e. it would appear that the not(this) is not working, and that all nav .current divs are faded to opacity:0:

```
$(".current").not(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, {
            duration: 2000,
            specialEasing: {
                opacity: 'linear',
            },

        });
```

I have created a jsfiddle with the relevant code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nickharambee/9DTKp/).  I also include the full script, and html and css for the nav bar below, and would be glad of some help to get this working.

Thanks,

Nick

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function ()
{

    var newHash = "",
        $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
        $pageWrap = $("#page-wrap"),
        baseHeight = 0,
        $el,
        $panel = $("#panel");

    $panel.visible = false;

    $("nav").delegate("a", "click", function ()
    {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
        $("a").not(this).removeClass('clicked');
        $(".current", this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, {
            duration: 100,
            specialEasing: {
                opacity: 'linear',
            },

        });

        return false;
    });

    $("#nav-bottom").delegate("a", "click", function ()
    {
        $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
        return false;
    });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function ()
    {

        newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

        if (newHash)
        {
            if ($panel.visible)
            {
                $pageWrap.animate({ height: "-=" + $panel.height() + "px" }, function ()
                {
                    $pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
                    $panel.visible = false;
                });
                $panel.slideUp();
                baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height() - $panel.height();
            }
            else
            {
                $pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
                baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();
            }

            $mainContent
                .find("#guts")
                .fadeOut(500, function ()
                {
                    $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function ()
                    {
                        $pageWrap.animate({ height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px" }, function ()
                        {
                            $mainContent.fadeIn(500);
                            $pageWrap.css("height", "auto");
                        });

//                        $("nav a").removeClass("current");
//                        $("nav a[href=\"" + newHash + "\"]").addClass("current");
                    });
                });
        };
    });

    $("#contact").click(function ()
    {
        $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
//        $(this).addClass("current");
//        $("#home, #about").removeClass("current");
        $panel.visible = true;
        return false;
    });

    $(".close").click(function ()
    {
        $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
//        $(curTab).addClass("current");
//        $("#contact").removeClass("current");
        $panel.visible = false;
        return false;
    });

    $("nav a").hover(
        function() {
            if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked')){

            $(".current", this).stop().animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, {
                duration: 300,
                specialEasing: {
                    opacity: 'linear',
                },

            });
            }
        }, function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked')){
            $(".current", this).stop().animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, {
                duration: 2000,
                specialEasing: {
                    opacity: 'linear',
                },

        });

        }
    });

    $(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

**HTML**

```
<nav>

<div id="nav1">
     <a href="index.html" class="fade" id="index">

     <div class="nav-image"><img src="images/bodhi-leaf-brown.png"></div>

     <div class="current"><img src="images/bodhi-leaf-green.png"></div>
     <div class="text"><img src="images/home.png"></div>

     </a>
</div>

<div id="nav2">
     <a href="about.html" class="fade" id="about">

     <div class="nav-image"><img src="images/bodhi-leaf-brown.png" class="flip"></div>

     <div class="current"><img src="images/bodhi-leaf-green.png" class="flip"></div>
     <div class="text"><img src="images/about.png"></div>

     </a>
</div>

<div id="nav3">

     <a href="index.html" class="" id="contact">

     <div class="nav-image"><img src="images/bodhi-leaf-brown.png"></div>

     <div class="current"><img src="images/bodhi-leaf-green.png"></div>
     <div class="text"><img src="images/contact.png"></div>

     </a>
</div>

</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav {
    width: 650px;
    height: 170px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100;
    left: 200;
}

#nav1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 120px;
}

#nav2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 340px;
}

#nav3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 560px;
}


.nav-image  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;

}

.current {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you use a non-disappearing demo on jsfiddle or any other demo site so when that demo site you have is gone, this question could be useful to future users?

Comment: Not sure without a working demo I can manipulate, but what about using the jquery object in the `not` call:  `$(".current").not($(this)).stop().animate({`

Comment: I have put a jsfiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nickharambee/9DTKp/).  As you can see, when you remove the section of code that is at the top of my original question, the newly clicked nav links do stay green, but the old links stay brown.  When the code is included, all links stay brown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `$(".current")` is selecting `<div>` elements.  The function is firing on events attached to `<a>` elements, so `this` is referring to `<a>` elements, so `not` is never matching the elements.

To get `not` to match, you need to select the `.current` element which is contained within `this` as such:

```
$(".current").not($(".current",this))
```

Answer (score 0):

So the basic issue here is that, in the click handler, `this` refers to the `a` element that's been clicked, which is the *parent* of the `div.current` element you're targeting. Try:

```
var $this = $(this),
    $others = $('nav a').not(this);

$(".current", this).stop().animate({
    opacity: 1
}, {
    duration: 100,
    specialEasing: {
        opacity: 'linear',
    },

});

$(".current", $others).stop().animate({
    opacity: 0
}, {
    duration: 2000,
    specialEasing: {
        opacity: 'linear',
    },

});
```